# How to render multiple data on Ejs template file from MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs, html-templates

Please look at the code and solve this problem

[image]

> **In the Image only One data is rendering at a time but I want to render
> more than one data from the database. In the mongo database there are
> three entries but when I take the data from the database only one data
> is rendering.**

**Below is the code I used to render data from the database**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3761628.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the array itself to the template instead of calling `res.render` for each entry:

```
const contacts = results.map(contact => ({
    Fname: contact.fname,
    Lname: contact.lname,
    Email: contact.email,
    Phone: contact.phoneNumber
}));

res.render("saved", {
    contacts
});
```

Then in your template use `forEach` to iterate the data and render each entry, e.g.:

```
<ul>
 <% contacts.forEach(function(contact) { %>
    <li> First Name:<%= contact.Fname %> Last Name:<%= contact.Lname%></li>
 <% }); %> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer It worked. Really I've been wondering for so long to find a solution for this. Once again thank you so much.